# Use PHP to create a menu?

Tags: php

I have a simple site with no database. Each page is in the ROOT DIRECTORY of the site and has page values set as follows:

```
<?php    
$page_title = "My Page Title";
$description = "Page Description";
$current_page = "home";
//Load header  
include_once('includes/header.php');
?>
```

How can I use PHP to generate a list of links to each page (for a navigation menu) using one of the values as the anchor text and add a class of active to the current page?

As the pages are in the root directory with other files, there needs to be a way to specify which pages appear in the menu and which don't and exclude other files eg robots.txt .htaccess

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to store the navigation in a database with the url and a menu flag to determine if it should be in the menu.

You can then grab the menu items from the database sort in whatever order you like and you will then also be able to automatically determine the current page by using the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` global variable. For example.

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE inMenu = 1;";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    echo "<ul>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $class = "";
        if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/" . $row['pageName']) {
             $class = "currentPage";
        }

        echo "<li {$class}>";
        echo "<a href='{$row['pageUrl']}'>{$row['pageName']}</a>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Or something to that affect. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have updated my question, I would rather not have to use a database. Thanks